# blacklist test requests from google analytics using watir

Tags: ruby, google-analytics, watir, webautomation

I have to  automate tests for a web application which runs google analytics script. I have chosen watir for the automation since I can script all the test cases with the same. The only problem is i dont know how to remove my test requests to the web apps from the google analytics report. Can anyone help me with the same? Is it possible to do that with watir? If not watir, is there any other web automation tool which I could use?

~Thanks and Regarads

Answer (score 2):

using your hosts file to send the google analytics requests to another server is probably a better way

Answer (score 0):

1. disable JavaScript in the browser that Watir drives, that will not execute Google analytics code
2. you can filter out requests that Watir made, I am sure there is a way in Google analytics to filter out specific IP or something similar